# CASE Statement MYSQL with Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 CASE statements: First CASE statement is as follows:

```
Case When ((cust_shipmentdate_awb Is Null OR cust_shipmentdate_awb = '') 
AND (comp_shipdate_awb IS NULL OR comp_shipdate_awb = '')) Then 'Pending'
ELSE 'Shipped' End AS shipment_status
```

The Second CASE statement is as follows:

```
Case When apbg_bal_pay_amt ='0' Then 'Received'
    Else 'Pending' End AS payment_status
```

Iam looking to write one more CASE statement named OVERALL_Status. That is basically a combination of both this CASES (shipment_status and payment_status), which means if Shipment status is 'Shipped' AND Payment_Status is 'Received' then Overall_status is 'Completed' else 'Not Completed'. Can anyone please help me on this. I am really struck here. I tried the combination of both the CASES, but not working:

```
Case When (cust_shipmentdate_awb Is Null OR cust_shipmentdate_awb = '') AND 
(comp_shipdate_awb IS NULL OR comp_shipdate_awb = '') AND (apbg_bal_pay_amt != '0') Then 
'Pending' ELSE 'Completed' End AS overall_status
```

Comment: If posible give the sql fiddle link what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions as I see it:
1. You make the current query a subquery and add another CASE statement on the result of the subquery. (the pretty solution as I see it)
2. You add another WHEN to the existing case. Combining the clauses in the first two WHEN clauses to get the result. (probably the most optimized solution)

Comment: Yes iam trying the second solution.

Comment: I tried this : Case When 
(commercial_logi_freight.cust_shipmentdate_awb Is Null OR commercial_logi_freight.cust_shipmentdate_awb = '') 
AND (commercial_logi_freight.comp_shipdate_awb IS NULL OR commercial_logi_freight.comp_shipdate_awb = '') 
AND (commercial_acc_supplier.apbg_bal_pay_amt != '0')  Then 'Pending'
ELSE 'Completed' End AS overall_status

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(case when (cust_shipmentdate_awb Is Null OR cust_shipmentdate_awb = '')  and
           (comp_shipdate_awb IS NULL OR comp_shipdate_awb = '')
      then 'Not Completed'
      when apbg_bal_pay_amt = '0' Then 'Completed'
      else 'Not Completed'
 end) as overall_status
```